# Hortonworks Sandbox

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform, hortonworks-sandbox

When i try to login into Hortonworks sandbox -> http://127.0.0.1:8888/# Dashboard with maria_dev as username and password.
I am unable to login.
what is the username and password for Sandbox HDP 2.5
[=I am getting the below screen after entered the mention user name and password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atLo3.png)

Answer (score 1):

The default login credentials of the sandbox are: **root/hadoop**

You can easily login via the built-in ssh client browsing http://127.0.0.1:4200/

Here you are also able to set an admin password for Ambari. Just execute the following command in the shell and follow the instruction:

```
[root@sandbox]# ambari-admin-password-reset
```

Now you should be able to login to ambari in the admin context.